# Elif and if not working or me not understanding

Tags: python, if-statement

Well my code is working, but when I type No if I want to retry to enter the password it doesn't work; it just goes to the enter password line (line 20). I have tried multiple ways to fix this but I simply cannot.

```
import time
import os

print ("Hello world.")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Waiting 5 seconds.")
time.sleep(5)
print ("You have waited 10 seconds.")
print ("Executing Chrome.")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Execution failed!")
password = input("Enter the execution password: ")
if password == 'password1234':
    os.system ('C:\\Users\\Harry\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
else:
    print ("Wrong password!")
    time.sleep(1)
    passretry = input("Do you want to try again? ")
    if passretry == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        passretry1 = input("Enter password: ") 
        if passretry1 == 'password1234':
            os.system ('C:\\Users\\Harry\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
    elif passretry == 'no' or 'No':
        print ("Closing...")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print ("Wrong password.")
        time.sleep(.5)
        print ("Retry limit exceeded, closing.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Someone needs to make a list of common Python misconceptions. The topic of `if a == x or y` would be on the top of the list.

Comment: @MarkRansom: There are already a few such lists (even the FAQ sort of has one), but for some reason this doesn't seem to be on them…

Comment: @MarkRansom - it's not just python where this misconception is common

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if passretry == 'yes' or 'Yes':
```

the above if statement is evaluated as: -

```
if (passretry == 'yes') or 'Yes':
```

Now, since `'Yes'` is evaluated to `True`, so, your `if` statement is always `True`, and hence you always have to enter new password.

---

You need to change the condition to: -

```
if passretry in ('yes', 'Yes'):
```

likewise, the following `elif` should be changed to: -

```
elif passretry in ('no', 'No'):
```

Comment: @RohitJain - thanks for showing the pythonic way :)

Answer (score 3):

This condition:

```
if passretry == 'yes' or 'Yes':
```

means "If `passretry == 'yes'` is true, or `'Yes'` is true".  `'Yes'` is always true, because a non-empty string counts as true.  That's why you're always taking the first code path.

You need to spell things out a little more:

```
if passretry == 'yes' or passretry == 'Yes':
```

(Or to make your code a bit more general:

```
if passretry.lower() == 'yes':
```

which would allow for people shouting `YES`.)

Answer (score 2):

You need another complete statement:

```
passretry == 'yes' or passretry == 'Yes':
```

The string 'Yes' always evaluates to True.